# Android detect speech recognition language

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I am working in an application that recognizes user voice and convert it to decimal , it should detect two languages **Arabic** , and **English**.

This my Intent to detect user input:

```
 Intent voicerecogize = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
 voicerecogize.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "ar-eg");
 startActivityForResult(voicerecogize, RESULT_SPEECH);
```

I need a method to detect which language user speaks either Arabic or English.

Comment: oke, very good :) where is the question here ?

Comment: I need method detect which language user speak , either Arabic or English

Comment: update your question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not listen for 2 languages at the same time with the current Android Speech Recognition API.
You can only listen for one language at a time.

What you could do is record the user input and then push the recorded input to one speech recognizer for English and one for Arabic, but there is no out-of-the-box API to do this.